# jQuery Tablesorter, fixed/static borders

Tags: jquery, static, row, tablesorter, border

I am a big fan of jQuery Tablesorter (http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/) but there is one function I can't seem to find, nor does anyone else seem to have posted about it.
What I would need is to have fixed borders on certain rows. For example, I have a table with 8 rows, I need a fixed border-bottom: 1px solid #000 on row #4 and a red one on row #6, regardless of the content & sorting, these borders needs to be fixed. Anyway to achieve that?

Any ideas, support is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sortStart` and `sortEnd` events. See http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html#events for docs.

Remove the css classes responsible for the borders on `sortStart` and then add them back on `sortEnd`. You'll also have to add them once on table initialization:

```
var $table = $('#the-table');

$table.tablesorter();

var set_classes = function() {
    $table.find('tbody tr:eq(3)').addClass('black-border');
    $table.find('tbody tr:eq(5)').addClass('red-border');
}

var clear_classes = function() {
    $table.find('tbody tr:eq(3)').removeClass('black-border');
    $table.find('tbody tr:eq(5)').removeClass('red-border');
}

set_classes();
$table.bind('sortStart', clear_classes).bind('sortEnd', set_classes);
```

And just for completeness sake, here is what your css classes would look like:

```
.black-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.red-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

Comment: Smart, will test when I get home.